# Why Integrate GP tool (ArcGIS) does not use the cluster tolerance as expected?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, arcgis-10.3, cluster-tolerance

Have spent some time on generalizing some datasets and got puzzled by the algorithm used by the [Integrate GP tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002s000000).

I have two points in a file geodatabase of 10.3 version, those points are located on a certain distance from each other. I run the Integrate tool (tried both inside and outside the editing session). The feature class is stored in a projected coordinate system (specifically, the WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere). I run the Integrate tool on this feature class with the cluster tolerance = 1000m.

I cannot comprehend how the cluster tolerance is used. I've added a scale bar while in Layout mode for illustration purposes. Here points will be integrated when the distance between them = ~2300m.

[image]

They stop collapsing into one feature in between when the distance gets larger than ~2800m. Any value smaller than that will move both points into a position that is right between them (i.e., they get integrated).
[image]

So, I could see two ways the cluster tolerance is used:

- if the distance between the two points is smaller than the cluster
  tolerance, they will be moved into a common central position; doesn't
  seem to work for me - they get integrated when distance between them > 1000m.
- if the circles around the points (with
  radius=cluster tolerance) intersect, they will be moved into a common
  central position (then they should be integrated if the distance
  between points < 2000m, which again is not the case.

**Can anyone explain how does the Integrate tool work in terms of cluster tolerance, because from my tests it doesn't make sense.**

I am on ArcGIS 10.3, but I've tested on 10.2 and got the same behaviour.

Comment: There is some information on clusters and tolerances on both http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006200000003000000 and http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n00000005000000 you may find helpful.

Comment: @ChrisW, a great page, shame I couldn't find it myself :) if no one will post any valid answer in a couple of days, please do wrap your comment into an answer which I will gladly accept.

Comment: I think it would probably be better if you formulate the answer, as while I found the resource and read it, I still couldn't quite put the pieces together - it seemed to me that with 1000m tolerance anything from about 1400m or closer would be integrated, but you're getting 2,800. I'm not sure I could make a legitimate question *answer* since I don't fully understand what I linked to. :)

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Is there any chance to you can post a brief self-answer to close off this one?